# Arduino with bmp280 sensor not entering void loop

Tags: sensors, communication, pressure

I've been working on a project in which I need to know my altitude. For this purpose I've been using the BMP280 sensor. But I have an issue.

I've been trying to test if the sensor works with the program "bmp280_sensortest.ino", already included in the library. When I open the serial monitor the message "BMP280 Sensor event test" is displayed, indicating that there is a valid sensor on board. Below that the temperature, pressure and altitude data should be displayed, but nothing happens.

I've added a simple `Serial.print("hello")` at the start of `void loop()`, but not even that is displayed. The program doesn't seem to enter `void loop()` and I don't know why.

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_BMP280.h>

Adafruit_BMP280 bmp; // use I2C interface
Adafruit_Sensor *bmp_temp = bmp.getTemperatureSensor();
Adafruit_Sensor *bmp_pressure = bmp.getPressureSensor();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(F("BMP280 Sensor event test"));

  if (!bmp.begin()) {
    Serial.println(F("Could not find a valid BMP280 sensor, check wiring!"));
    while (1) delay(10);
  }

  /* Default settings from datasheet. */
  bmp.setSampling(Adafruit_BMP280::MODE_NORMAL,     /* Operating Mode. */
                  Adafruit_BMP280::SAMPLING_X2,     /* Temp. oversampling */
                  Adafruit_BMP280::SAMPLING_X16,    /* Pressure oversampling */
                  Adafruit_BMP280::FILTER_X16,      /* Filtering. */
                  Adafruit_BMP280::STANDBY_MS_500); /* Standby time. */

  bmp_temp->printSensorDetails();
}

void loop() {
  sensors_event_t temp_event, pressure_event;
  bmp_temp->getEvent(&temp_event);
  bmp_pressure->getEvent(&pressure_event);
  
  Serial.print("hello");
  Serial.print(F("Temperature = "));
  Serial.print(temp_event.temperature);
  Serial.println(" *C");

  Serial.print(F("Pressure = "));
  Serial.print(pressure_event.pressure);
  Serial.println(" hPa");

  Serial.println();
  delay(2000);
}
```

Any reply is greatly appreciated.
edit:

if I remove
`!bmp.begin()`

from the if statement and replace it with a 1 it enters the void loop but it displays 0°C and 0pa

Comment: If you are using `Serial.print("hello");` to test the entering of `void loop()`, you should follow it with `Serial.flush();` so that you know your message has been sent before your code has an opportunity to lock up, because if that happens the absence of the "Hello" message might lead you to believe that you didn't make it to that line when you in fact did.

Comment: put print statements throughout setup()

Comment: But you don't get the "check wiring" message? ;)

Comment: Add prints after every call in setup to pin down which of those calls does not return...

Comment: Does your BMP280 show up if you run the [I2C scanner sketch](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner/)? Does that sketch fail to run to completion?

Comment: @timemage the I2C scanner sketch is stuck at 'scanning...'

Comment: There is something fundamental going on then and not enough information to provide a proper answer that matches your question.  It may be as @SimSon suggested, wiring.  It may be that your pull-up resistors are too weak or non-existent.  A simple way to lock up the AVR Wire implementation is to hold SCL LOW indefinitely.  But it could be any number of other things.

Comment: What you might do is delete this question *before* it is "answered".  Work on your wiring, and if you're still having trouble with it start a new question to the effect "why is my bme280 connected to nano ble etc etc not show up in the i2c scanner" and provide details needed to trouble shoot that.  E.g. link to the bme280 breakout used.  Pictures of wiring, etc.  Then whatever answer that results will match the question.  Though, you'll probably figure it out on your own.

Comment: "replace it with a 1 it enters the void loop" - in this case the sketch is *not* supposed to enter the loop, instead it will get stuck in the `while(1)` loop. Please clarify this point. An all time classic is missing pullup resistors, do you have those attached?

Answer (score 1):

It could be a faulty library/sensor, most likely the sensor, sometimes sensors can begin but then another connection could be faulty or the chip itself is faulty and so the Arduino might just be waiting forever for a response that will never come.

To see where it gets stuck, you can add Serial.println(F("1")); after bmp.setsampling then Serial.println(F("2"));  after bmp_temp->printSensorDetails to see where exactly it's getting stuck

One thing I also like to do is to buy two/three of a sensor, so that I can replace a sensor with another one. That way if a piece of code doesn't work for all three sensors then I can pretty sure it's a problem with the code and not the device. Not sure if you have a spare sensor to try that but I would recommend it in future